# Lowering the cardinality of a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Given a set X with a certain cardinality, there are explicit constructions for getting a set with the "next bigger" cardinality, e.g. constructing the power set.

Does some analogous construction exist for the reverse, i.e. getting a set with the next smaller cardinality?

Comment: Pick a single point?

Comment: Henno: True, but I was looking for something nontrivial ;) I will edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: The power set only has the "next bigger" cardinality if we assume the continuum hypothesis.

Comment: Yes, thats why it is in quotes. I fear that I don't have the mathematical expertise to ask this question precisely, so feel free to assume anything that I have forgotten.

Comment: Perhaps a [quotient set construction](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594458/definition-of-quotient-set) using an equivalence relation might work, but I can't think of any nontrivial examples that always lower the cardinality of an infinite set. *(moments later)* When I wrote the above, I didn't realize you wanted the "next lower cardinality" (I was distracted while writing it . . .), but I'll leave my comment here in case you're willing to settle for simply lowering the cardinality.

Comment: @SBareS The power set only has the next bigger cardinality if we assume the *generalized* continuum hypothesis.

Comment: @Benno There may not be a "next smaller" cardinality. If $\kappa$ is a limit cardinal (e.g. $\kappa = \aleph_0$, or $\kappa = \aleph_{\omega}$) then there is no such thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general no, because not every cardinality has a "next-smaller" cardinality.  In particular, if $\kappa$ is a limit cardinal then it is not a successor cardinal, so there is no cardinal $\lambda$ such that $\kappa = \lambda^+$.

However, if $\kappa$ is a successor cardinal, or if for a limit cardinal you're ok with finding a subset of any smaller cardinality, the procedure is the same:

Let $\kappa$ well-order $S$, pick your desired cardinal $\lambda < \kappa$, let $x$ be the element of $S$ with order-type $\lambda$, and then let $T = \{s \in S : s < x\}$.

Answer (score 3):

This is impossible as there just is no "next smaller cardinality" in general. Just consider $\mathbb{N}$, what do you want to do. It is impossible.