# Quotient Set of an Equivalence Relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Let $A = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and $R = \{(1,1) , (1,2) , (2,1) , (2,2) ,
> (3,3), (3,4) , (4,4)\}.$
>
> Is $R$ an equivalence relation on $A$? If so, find its quotient set.

I know that it is an equivalence relation. 
I found that it was Symmetric, Reflexive, and Transitive. Because it meets these three standards it is an equivalence relation.

But I'm very confused as to what/how I find it's quotient set. Any information is great!

Thanks!

Comment: Elements in the quotient sets are just equivalence classes under the relation. Can you find the equivalence class of each element in $A$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Definition of "quotient set"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594458/definition-of-quotient-set)

Comment: Observe that $(4,3) \notin R$ although $(3,4) \in R$.

Comment: If you were to include $(4,3)$ in the relation as well... the short answer is that the quotient set is merely the set of equivalence classes.  In this case you have the "smaller numbers" and the "larger numbers" and could be written as $\{[1],[3]\}$ or equivalently as $\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}$ or in several other ways.